# string formatting is not working in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I have been trying to learn tkinter and have created something that post the results of a bunch of functions, and in the terminal the string formats works, but in the gui the string format does not work at all. I am super confused on why?

The code is below:

```py
from tkinter import *
import ForFeesCovered

root = Tk()
root.title("Staff Fee Calculator")
root.geometry("375x400")

myLabel = Label(root,
            text="Staff Fee Calculator")

e = Entry(root,
      width=50,
      borderwidth=5)


def output():
    input_file = e.get()
    f = ForFeesCovered.readfile(input_file)
    file = ForFeesCovered.readfile(input_file)
    staff = ForFeesCovered.getnamesofstaff(f)
    staff.sort(reverse=False)
    dic = ForFeesCovered.sort_dic(staff)

    line_skip = 1
    for lines in file:
        line = lines.strip().split(",")
        if line_skip != 1:
        total = float("        
        {:.2f}".format(ForFeesCovered.getfeesforline(line)))
            name = ForFeesCovered.get_name_of_staff(line, staff)
            dic = ForFeesCovered.populating_dic(dic, name, total)
        else:
            line_skip += 1

    string_dic = ""
    result_file = open("result.txt", "w+")
    for key in dic:
        result_file.write("{} : {}\n".format(key, dic[key]))
        string_dic = string_dic + "{:30} : {:>30}\n".format(key,         
dic[key])
        print(string_dic)
    result_file.close()

    output_dic = Label(root, text=string_dic, justify=LEFT)
    output_dic.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=20)

submit = Button(root, text="Submit", command=output)

myLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
e.grid(row=1, column=0,)
submit.grid(row=1, column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: There is actually alot of code, try to include the part that has the error only?

Answer (score 0):

The terminal is using a fixed-width font, the GUI is using a variable-width font.

If you are trying to line things up with spaces, you will need to used a fixed-width font.